# random number and tkinter not working

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm new to python as i've only used it for 4 months, im trying to program a tkinter window in which a label displays a random number ever second i have this so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
testy = "0"
root = Tk()
lbl = Label(root,text="0")

def callback():
    global testy
    lbl.configure(text=testy)
    testy = str(randint(0,10))
    root.after(2000,callback)
lbl.pack()
root.after(2000,callback)
root.mainloop()
```

any help is apprieciated

Comment: This works fine, you're just calling every two seconds instead of one.

Comment: How do you define "not working"? This exact code seems to work fine, except it's every two seconds instead of every one. Is it that  you don't understand how to change the interval to one second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours seems to work for me, this is a slightly more condensed version however which is called every 1 second instead of 2, as that is what you outlined wanting in your question.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack()

def replace_text():
    lbl.config(text=str(random.random()))
    root.after(1000, replace_text)

replace_text()
root.mainloop()
```